# Sitecore jss nextjs app deployment to azure static web app giving Error: Backend call failure

Tags: deployment, web-deploy

I have deployed a **Sitecore Jss Next.js** application to Azure as a static web app, but when I am accessing the URL it is giving the following error:

```
Backend call failure
```

Here are the steps that I followed:

1. Build the Sitecore nextjs app.
2. Replaced the  `SITECORE_API_KEY`(sskey from xmc
   portal), `GRAPH_QL_ENDPOINT`, `JSS_APP_NAME` (app from xmc portal),
   `FETCH_WITH` with your actual xm cloud portal values.
3. Made sure app running file with xmcloud portal in local.
4. Pushed my code to github in main branch.
5. Created linux os azure static web app and it created github action automatically after few modification app deployed.
6. I added the azure configuration appsettings: `SITECORE_API_KEY` (sskey from xmc portal), `GRAPH_QL_ENDPOINT`, `JSS_APP_NAME` (app from xmc portal), `FETCH_WITH`

Using the folllowing json:

```
{
"name": "FETCH_WITH",
"value": "GraphQL"
},
{
"name": "GRAPH_QL_ENDPOINT",
"value": "https://edge.sitecorecloud.io/api/graphql/v1"
},
{
"name": "JSS_APP_NAME",
"value": "nextjs-sample"
},
{
"name": "JSS_EDITING_SECRET",
"value": "adf7854zaKx4VAg2iuxxxx89xx"
},
{
"name": "PUBLIC_URL",
"value": "https://azuestaticjssdemoxx.azurestaticapps.net"
},
{
"name": "serverSideRenderingEngineApplicationUrl",
"value": "https://azuestaticjssdemoxx.azurestaticapps.net"
},
{
"name": "serverSideRenderingEngineEndpointUrl",
"value": "https://azuestaticjssdemoxx.azurestaticapps.net/api/editing/render"
},
{
"name": "SITECORE_API_HOST",
"value": "xm cloud portal content editor url"
},
{
"name": "SITECORE_API_KEY",
"value": "ssapi key from xm portal"
}
```

I added the same values to `.env` and sitecore xm cloud portal app.
I published the xm cloud portal and deployed the project to xm edge.

When I try to access the URL (hypothetical URL): `https://azuestaticjssdemoxx.azurestaticapps.net`

I am getting the error:

```
backend failure
```

I can see the following exception in application insights:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: at Mono.Unix.UnixFileSystemInfo.AssertValid (Mono.Posix.NETStandard, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51) at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Workers.Http.HttpWorkerProcess.AssignUserExecutePermissionsIfNotExists (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script, Version=4.21.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: /src/azure-functions-host/src/WebJobs.Script/Workers/Http/HttpWorkerProcess.cs:75
```

If you have ever faced this issue with while deploying a **Sitecore Next.js** application to Azure static web app, please share your advice and suggestions thanks.